# AWS SSO - List users assigned with an aws account

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, aws-sso

I have the list of all AWS accounts in my organization. I need to list the users present in each account via API.
Through the documentation [List account assigments](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sso-admin.html#SSOAdmin.Client.list_account_assignments),
I can list only passing as parameters **account** + **permission set**.
I wanted it to list all users, just like when I click on the account via console, as shown in the image:
[image]
Can anyone tell me if this is possible?

Comment: `aws iam list-users`

Comment: @Asdfg These users coming from sso, do not appear in the iam of the accounts.
These are users that come from an external idp (okta) to sso.

Comment: my bad. try `aws identitystore list-users`. more info here at https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/identitystore/list-users.html. you may have to pass `--identity-store-id`

Comment: @Asdfg This method does not allow grouping by account. It only returns users.

Comment: Be curious. Explore more. I am sure you will find a solution.

Comment: related?: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/iam-identity-center-report-permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I managed to do it was as follows:

1. [List all organization accounts](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/organizations.html#Organizations.Client.list_accounts)
2. [For each account, list all permission sets](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sso-admin.html#SSOAdmin.Client.list_permission_sets_provisioned_to_account)
3. [With the account id and permission set, you can list users](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sso-admin.html#SSOAdmin.Client.list_account_assignments)

You need to perform this process on all accounts and group users by account. It's a little tedious but it's the only way I found.
I hope you can improve this library in the future.

Comment: Still the only answer I can find to do this, I'm amazed AWS doesn't have a better way to do this!